# Errors While Trying to Install mkusb

Tags: mkusb

I am seeing errors when I try to install mkusb. Upon repeatedly getting the error, I first purged mkusb using the instructions on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui).

Upon still getting errors upon my next attempt, I repeated the purge and see the following result:

---

```
    thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo apt-get purge mkusb
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package 'mkusb' is not installed, so not removed
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 336 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: update-desktop-database: Permission denied
    dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     desktop-file-utils
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

When I try to install mkusb, I see the following, which is similar to what was occurring before the purge:

---

```
thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9z0r3jqp/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9z0r3jqp/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 54B8C8AC from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp9z0r3jqp/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 54B8C8AC: public key "Launchpad PPA for MKUSB" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]             
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]         
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x xenial InRelease [4,646 B]           
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg                 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB] 
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/komodo-edit/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Ign:2 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                     
Ign:13 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release
Ign:14 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:15 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en          
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps all Packages
Ign:17 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign:19 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Fetched 331 kB in 3s (104 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
E: Failed to fetch http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo apt-get install mkusb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mkusb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 336 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/50.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 193 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mkusb.
(Reading database ... 223633 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mkusb_12.3.2-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking mkusb (12.3.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: update-desktop-database: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Setting up mkusb (12.3.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 desktop-file-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
thethirdeyeagain@thethirdeyeagain:~$ sudo apt-get install mkusb-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mkusb-nox is already the newest version (12.3.2-1ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 336 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: update-desktop-database: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 desktop-file-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Sorry for the wall of text. Please let me know if you would like for me to delete all except a certain portion that is relevant.

I would welcome any suggestions for how to troubleshoot or what else to try.

Thanks to DK Bose for the edit to make the log so much easier to read! My attempt at quoting it was making it one continuous stream of text. I now see some of the tips for formatting and will play around with it to see if I can make it look more like what you did next time around.

Comment: It seems you have problems with the program package `desktop-file-utils`. I don't know if that will interfere with the use of `mkusb` or if `mkusb` should be blamed. But I have both these packages installed in Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS without problems. And before I had 16.04.1 LTS where `mkusb` worked too (you seem to have 16.04 (Xenial)). Have you tested if `mkusb` works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions form https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb to install mksub. If it gets stuck at 35% close the terminal and type "sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi" without the quotation marks. Hope this is useful.